# Using different templates in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up 2 different templates in my Django app using 2 different view methods. Weird thing is that when I call temp2, the url in my browser is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/temp2/` but it shows the html inside temp1.

This is my url.py inside myWeb:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^template1/', include('TeachingTool.urls')),
    url(r'^template2/', include('TeachingTool.urls')),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is my url.py inside myteachingapp:

```
   from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.func1, name = 'first'),
        url(r'^$', views.func2, name = 'second'),

    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

How can I separate this templates? I think that is has to be inside the url.py of myteachingapp as its taking the objects created inside the views.func1 because those are the ones been printed out when calling template2.

EDIT:

My view.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from TeachingTool.classes.alphabet import alphabet

from .forms import keyInput

# Create your views here.


def func1(request):
    form = keyInput(request.POST or None)
    test = alphabet()
    x = test.getListLetter()
    context = {"form": form,
                'x': x,
                "test" : test
     }

    if form.is_valid():
        form.cleaned_data
        test.getLetter(form.key)
        context = {"form": form,
                    'x': x,
                    "test" : test
        }

    return render(request, 'temp1.html', context)

def func2(request):
    test = alphabet()
    s = test.getListLetter()
    context = { 's': s,
    }
    return render(request, 'temp2.html', context)
```

Comment: You should share your views.py

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the sharing idea? I'm new to Django.

Comment: By "share" Ringil means post your view method. :)

Comment: Added the view methods, please check post!

Comment: Your urlpatterns are not quite right at the moment. Do you want `/template1/` to go to `func1`, and `/template2/` to go to `func2`?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to use func1 with template1 and func2 with template2. I call template2 and I get exacly to the output in template1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem at the moment is that you are using the same regex for two views. The first url will always match, and the second will never be called.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.func1, name = 'first'),
    url(r'^$', views.func2, name = 'second'),
]
```

I would change it to

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^template1/$', views.func1, name = 'first'),
    url(r'^template2/$', views.func2, name = 'second'),
]
```

Then change your root url conf to

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('TeachingTool.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Note that you only need to include `TeachingTool.urls` once.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening when your server recieves the url '/template2' is the following:

- Your root url file is checked, and the pattern '/template2' is recognised by the third pattern.
- The included url file is checked with  the remaining part of the url ( here, nothing remains).
- 'nothing' is matched by the first pattern in myTeachingTool.url, wich calls the function views.func1.

You can achieve what you want by changing the patterns:

In myWeb.url:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^', include('TeachingTool.urls')),
]
```

In TeachingTool.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^template1/$', views.func1, name = 'first'),
    url(r'^template2/$', views.func2, name = 'second'),
]
```